# How do I get items categories from the WooCommerce cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing the function which should check up whether there is in the cart an item, which has a particular category.

My idea was:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'remove_flat_rate_from_used_products', 10, 2 );

function remove_flat_rate_from_used_products($rates, $package) {
    if( is_woocommerce() && ( is_checkout() || is_cart() ) ) {
        if( check_whether_item_has_the_category() ) {
            unset( $rates['flat_rate'] );
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

I guessed, the get_cart() function returns the contents of the cart, and I would be able to get information about items categories out there. I need to know the structure of the array get_cart() returns, so I wrote:

```
function check_whether_item_has_the_category() {
    global $woocommerce;

    var_dump(WC()->cart->get_cart());
}
```

And got

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-shipping.php on line 295
```

Then I tried find the category name in results of the get_cart() function:

```
function check_whether_item_has_the_category() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if( in_array('used', WC()->cart->get_cart()) ) {
        echo 'do something';
    }
}
```

And got the same error.

The use of $woocommerce instead of WC() give nothing, as well as the remove of `global $woocommerce`

What am I doing wrong and how do I get items categories (or check them for existing of the particular one)?

Comment: what if you have more than one product in cart with different categories, should the flat rate still be unset?

Comment: Yes, if there is at least one product with the category, the flat rate should be unset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$package` contains also the cart contents (`$package['contents']`), that is an array with all the products in cart.

So you can loop through that and see if the single product has the category wanted. To get the categories you can use [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms):

```
function remove_flat_rate_from_used_products($rates, $package) {

    // for each product in cart...
    foreach ($package['contents'] as $product) {
        // get product categories
        $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( $product['product_id'], 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'names') );
        // if it has category_name unset flat rate
        if( in_array('category_name', $product_cats) ) {
            unset( $rates['flat_rate'] );
            break;
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a good solution. It must perfectly work in the described situation. I worked out a similar solution by trial and error and spent about 3 hours. Also, there was the mistake that I tried to use the WooCommerce conditional tags in functions.php.